# Equation describing an elliptical orbit using time and angle

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, dynamical-systems, physics, polar-coordinates

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to describe the orbits of the planets in the solar system using the polar equation of an ellipse.

Below is an equation I got from [here](https://www.hilarispublisher.com/open-access/mathematically-describing-planetary-orbits-in-two-dimensions-2168-9679-1000414.pdf).
$$
r = \frac{b^{2}}{a - c \cos \theta} 
$$

Where
$a$ is the semi-major axis,
$b$ is the semi-minor axis,
$c$ is the distance between the center of the orbit and a focus point of the orbit $(c^2 = a^2 - b^2)$. The sun is at one of these foci, so $c$ is the distance between the center of the orbit/ellipse and the sun, the origin of the graph. This form of the equation also assumes no displacement of the ellipse in the $y$ direction from the origin.

This equation does relate the radius $r$ of a point on the ellipse as a function of the angle $\theta$ it makes with the origin.

However, I am trying to look for an equation that models the angle $\theta$ as a function of time $t$. For example, if $T$ was the period of one full orbit, then after $T$ seconds, the change in angle should be $2\pi$ radians. In other words, where if $f(t) = \theta$, $f(T) = 2\pi$ or $0$.

Considering that I have the values for $a$, $b$, and $c$, the orbital period $T$, and the linear speed $v$ of each planet, and since I cannot use the radius directly (because it is not constant across the ellipse), how could I derive the polar angle $\theta$ as a function of time $t$ without $r$?

Comment: The angle $\theta$ in your equation is called the eccentric anomaly, the angle from the Sun to the planet is called the true anomaly, and the angular parameter of the form $2\pi t/T$ is called the mean anomaly. You can blame Johannes Kepler for the odd names. ;) All of these angles equal zero at the perihelion point. The key equation connecting the mean anomaly $M$ & eccentric anomaly is called [Kepler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) $$M = \theta - e\sin\theta$$

Comment: @PM2Ring : $θ$ as used in the question is the true anomaly, so one needs a new name for the eccentric anomaly, like $ε$. They are connected via $$\tan\fracθ2=\sqrt{\frac{1+e}{1-e}}\tan\fracε2, ~~~ |θ-ε|<\pi.$$ Except on a circular orbit, these angles are different. Note that to make the formulas compatible to the question, $e=-c/a$. Then indeed $ωt=M=ε-e\sinε$ describes the time dynamic.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Oops! You're correct. My excuse is I tend to use $\nu$ for the true anomaly and $\theta$ for the eccentricity anomaly. But I should've remembered that $$r=\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos\nu}$$ and eccentric anomaly gives the simpler $$r=a(1-e\cos\theta)$$ As well as the tan formula connecting them, there's $$\cos\theta=\frac{e+\cos\nu}{1+e\cos\nu}$$ and $$\cos\nu=\frac{\cos\theta-e}{1-e\cos\theta}$$

Comment: Silly observation: So there is the $(\nu,\theta)$ convention, the $(\phi,E)$ convention (aside my personal use of $(θ,ε)$). Is there an established divide that depends on the branch of science/engineering, like astronomy vs. rocket science ... ? @PM2Ring

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm not sure. Wikipedia adds to the confusion by mixing conventions on the same page. :( I guess the clearest convention is to use $M,E,\theta$ for mean, eccentric, and true anomaly, respectively. FWIW, $\varepsilon$ is often used for the obliquity of the ecliptic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the time dynamic the Newton gravity law additionally results in the second Kepler law
$$
r^2\dotθ=L=const.\tag1
$$
that allows to solve the angle-time problem via numerical integration.

One can also try to solve it symbolically, or at least reduce it to a simpler non-ODE form. Eliminating first $r$ gives
$$
L=\frac{b^4\dotθ}{(a-c\cosθ)^2}.\tag2
$$
For integrals of fractions in trigonometric functions the recommendation is to use  the half-angle tangent $u=\tan\fracθ2$ with $\dot u=\frac12(1+u^2)\dotθ$ and $\cos θ=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$. The equation simplifies to
$$
\frac{L}{b^4}=\frac{2(1+u^2)\dot u}{((a-c)+(a+c)u^2)^2}\tag3
$$
This form now strongly suggests to set (using again a half-angle in the tangent for symmetry)
\begin{align}
\tan\fracε2&=\sqrt{\frac{a+c}{a-c}}u\tag4
\\
\implies 
(a-c)+(a+c)u^2&=(a-c)\sec^2\fracε2\tag{5a}\\
1+u^2&=\frac{(a+c)\cos^2\fracε2+(a-c)\sin^2\fracε2}{a+c}\sec^2\fracε2=\frac{a+c\cosε}{a+c}\sec^2\fracε2\tag{5b}
\\
1-u^2&=\frac{(a+c)\cos^2\fracε2-(a-c)\sin^2\fracε2}{a+c}\sec^2\fracε2=\frac{c+a\cosε}{a+c}\sec^2\fracε2\tag{5c}
\end{align}
With the derivative formulas
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\dotε}2\left(1+\frac{a+c}{a-c}u^2\right)&=\sqrt{\frac{a+c}{a-c}}\dot u\tag{6a}
\\\text{ or }~~
\dotε((a-c)+(a+c)u^2)&=2b\dot u\tag{6b}
\end{align}$$
one can insert and eliminate $u$ for $ε$, simplifying the equation to
$$\begin{align}
\frac{L}{b^3}&=\frac{(1+u^2) \dotε}{(a-c)+(a+c)u^2}
=\frac{a+c\cosε}{a^2-c^2}\dotε\tag{7a}
\\~\\
\frac{L}{b}&=(a+c\cosε)\dotε \tag{7b}
\end{align}$$
Now with an arbitrary change of the momentum constant to $L=ab\omega$, integration results in the Kepler equation
$$\tag8
ωt=ε+\frac{c}{a}\sinε, ~~~ \tan\fracθ2=\sqrt{\frac{a-c}{a+c}}\tan \fracε2
$$
The integration constant was left out which is correct if time $t=0$ corresponds to apoapsis with $θ=0$, where $r=\frac{b^2}{a-c}=a+c$ and thus also $ε=0$. In this context $ε$ is called<sup>*</sup> the [eccentric anomaly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eccentric_anomaly) (and $θ$ the true anomaly, $M=ωt$ the mean anomaly, there might have been something lost in the historic process, one would think that anomaly refers to the deviation from circular motion.)

For the Cartesian coordinates one gets from the half-angle formulas
\begin{alignat}{1}
x=r\cosθ&=\frac{b^2(1-u^2)}{(a-c)+(a+c)u^2}&=c+a\cosε\tag{9a}\\
y=r\sinθ&=\frac{b^2·2u}{(a-c)+(a+c)u^2}&=b\sinε\tag{9b}
\end{alignat}

---

*** Note that this deviates from the common definitions in that the anomalies are the angles at the gravity center relative to the pericenter position, not as here to the apocenter position.

Comment: Thank you for the derivation of the Kepler equation using _ω_, __, and _ε_, the eccentric anomaly! I would just like to ask how one could equalize _ε_ in two versions of this equation in order to solve for _t_ as an unknown variable (where each equation would have a unique given value for _ω_, _c_, and _a_).

Comment: Setting $ε_1=ε_2$ would give the same angle from the center $(-c_k,0)$ of the ellipse, not from the focal point. Note that from the general physics, $L=\sqrt{GMa(1-e^2)}=b\sqrt{\frac{GM}{a}}$ so $ω=L/ab=\sqrt{\frac{GM}{a^3}}$ in accord with the third Kepler law. So if you start with aligned apgee (or corrected by changing the sign of $c$ at aligned perigee), then find times where $(ω_2-ω_1)t=2k\pi$ and solve the Kepler equation for one of $ε_k$, which automatically also gives the solution of the other.

Comment: Sorry yes, I was looking for getting the same angle from the focal point (0,0) of the ellipses, not from the center. This means that if my intentions are correct this time, I want to know how to equalize the true anomalies ($θ_1$=$θ_2$), and similarly to the equation you suggested ($(ω_2−ω_1)=2$), find the various values of _t_ by changing _k_.

Comment: Obviously, they are related, if $θ_1=θ_2+2kπ$, then also $ε_1$ and $ε_2+2kπ$ are close together. I'm not sure that there is any nice solution. One can, staying with the apogee convention, reduce the first equation to $$\sqrt{\frac{a_1-c_1}{a_1+c_1}}\tan\frac{ε_1}2=\sqrt{\frac{a_2-c_2}{a_2+c_2}}\tan\frac{ε_2}2$$ along with the Kepler equations. This gives 3 equations for the 3 variables $(t,ε_1,ε_2)$ with initial values $t=2\pi k/(ω_2−ω_1)$, $ε_k=ω_kt-\frac{c_k}{a_k}\sin(ω_kt)$, $k=1,2$. I'm not sure if one could improve here against a general non-linear solver.

Comment: I was looking back through your outline and I didn't quite understand what happened to the $u^2$ in the denominator here:

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{L}{b^{3}}=\frac{\left(1+u^{2}\right) \dot{\varepsilon}}{(a-c)+(a+c) u^{2}}=\frac{a+c \cos \varepsilon}{a^{2}-c^{2}} \dot{\varepsilon}
\end{array}
$$

I understand that $(1+u^2)$ is replaced with the fraction $
\frac{a+c \cos \varepsilon}{a+c} \sec ^{2}\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
$, but I don't understand what happens so that $\sec^{2}\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $(a+c)u^2$ cancel out and give the result you calculated. Could you clarify this?

Comment: This is the consequence of inserting eqns. (5a) and (5b), in their ratio the secant square cancels.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some physics here, in particular, the conservation of angular momentum. $$L = \overrightarrow r \times \overrightarrow p$$
where $\overrightarrow r$ is the position vector and $\overrightarrow p$ is the momentum, or mass times velocity.  Essentially, you can't bring time into the problem without describing how the particle moves.

To shortcut some of that, you could use Kepler's observation that the planet sweeps out equal areas in equal times.  That could give you a relationship between $d\theta$ and $dt$.